# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique global handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to figure out a graceful way to handle a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception globally for all my ActiveRecord code.  I know about the `validates_uniqueness_of` validation but I want to rescue the exception directly as I have a constraint on the database in order to avoid bad data due to race conditions.  I also don't want to create a bunch of custom methods that directly handle the exception every time I want to save or update an object where this constraint can be violated.

I would prefer not to monkey patch ActiveRecord methods like `save()` but I am beginning to think that achieving graceful exception handling for all ActiveRecord objects in my code might require that.  Below is some code that demonstrates what a solution would look like:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post

  def save(*args)
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => error
    errors[:base] << error.message
    false
  end

end
```

While this works if I call save directly on a Photo object it won't work if I save the object through another model using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `validates_associated`.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks

**Update**
The desired outcome is to handle the exception and just add a key/value pair to the object's errors hash and then display form errors back to the user telling them that the email has been taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was the `inverse_of` option when defining the association on each of the models.  What `inverse_of` does is it causes rails to use the in memory instance of the associated object as opposed to going to the db to fetch the record.  I created a save method in the `Photo` model that looks like this:

```
  def save(*args)
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => error
    post.errors[:base] << "You can only have one photo be your header photo"
    false
  end
```

In the rescue block, when I call `post.errors` I am getting the unsaved, associated post object rather than rails looking for one in the db based on `photo.post_id` which at this point is nil because the photo object is invalid which caused the post not to be persisted to the db.

Here are the docs for `inverse_of`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from) Rails Guide. In short, you can use the `rescue_from` method to register a handler for exceptions. If you use it in ApplicationController then it'll be inherited by all other controllers.

Here's the example from the Guide:

> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found
>
>   private
>
>     def record_not_found
>       render plain: "404 Not Found", status: 404
>     end
> end
> ```

Go [take a look](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from) for more information and an additional example.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jordan.  I know about `rescue_from` but I don't want to return a status code as much as I want to just add another key/value pair to the errors hash on the object itself.  I should have been more specific.  I'll update the question to reflect my desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

My gem [activerecord-transactionable](https://github.com/pboling/activerecord-transactionable) allows you to do all of the following (a la carte):

1. rescue
2. retry with alternate logic (switch from `create` to `find`, for example)
3. add errors to the record that failed to save
4. use locking
5. use nested transactions
6. handle different kinds of database errors in different ways